# How to read resource of asp.net page from utility class

Tags: .net, asp.net, resources

I need to get a string from resource file of page from utility class.

I tried

```
         ResourceManager resources = 
            new ResourceManager(
                "Company.Application.Folder.App_LocalResources.Page.aspx", 
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        string value = resources.GetString("ResourceName");
```

but got an exception that resource not found.
I tried "Company.Application.Folder.Page.aspx" as a path as well.

Could you please help me to compose the right resource path.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through the properties.

```
Company.Application.Properties.Resources.ResourceName
```

(Assuming Company.Application is the default namespace)